# Android app being deleted from LG Allys when phone turns off

Tags: android, google-play

It appears as though everyone using my application on an LG Ally is having to redownload the application every time they turn off their phone.

I've received the folling market comments relating to the issue:

```
"Is great when it works. But if i shut my phone off i have to reinstall it. Lg ally."

"Great quick ref. I do have to redownload it every time my cell updates. Lg Ally"
```

And the following report in an email:

```
"The one problem that I have with it is should I turn my pohone off or the battery dies completly I have to redownload and install again. I was wondering if there was a way to fix this. I am using an LG Ally with the latest android sofware what ever that may be. Thank you for the app and your time."
```

Based on a quick google, the LG Ally currently has Android 2.1.

My application requests the following permissions:

```
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

and is using copy protection.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've read the problem has to do with the Ally specifically and the android Market.
They're saying that if copy-protection is turned off it should work normally.

from the [Verizon Community Forums](http://community.vzw.com/t5/Other-Android-Devices/LG-Ally-2-1-Update-starts-Fri-9-17-10/m-p/295906#M7312)

> > I'm an app developer and this update has effected many of my users (with the LG Ally).  Uninstalling/reinstalling fixes the problem temporarily but then after a reboot the issue is back.
> >
> > I provided the app to user's outside the market and the problem was fixed.  The only difference is the version from the Market has "copy-protection" enabled.  So my guess is Verizon messed up apps with copy-protection somehow.
> >
> > Just a tip if you are experiencing issues with apps, ask the app developers if the issue is with copy-protection and if they will turn copy-protection off in the Market or provide the app to you some other way.
> >     -Peter